# Нарисовать графики из двух датафреймов на одном в ggplot2 в R

Tags: r, ggplot2

У меня есть набор цифр, соответствующих двум распределениям - длины векторов разные, поэтому я не могу свести их в один датафрейм - делаю из них два, с1 и с2. Каким параметром можно нарисовать гистограммы для обоих векторов в ggplot2 на одном графике?
Пример:

```
v1 = [1,2,1,1,2,0]
v2 = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.5,1,3,4]
c1 = data.frame(v1)
c2 = data.frame(v2)
ggplot(c1, aes(x = c1[,1])) + geom_histogram()
ggplot(c2, aes(x = c2[,1])) + geom_histogram() #затирает предыдущий график,а хотелось бы добавить
```

Comment: пример бы посмотреть, то что вы делаете и у вас не получается

Comment: @stack-it, дополнила вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- data.frame()
x <- rbind(x, data.frame(v=c1$v1, type='val1'))
x <- rbind(x, data.frame(v=c2$v2, type='val2'))
ggplot(data=x) + geom_histogram(aes(x = v, fill=type, color=type), position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот пример:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# merge (rbind) dataframes
plotDat <- rbindlist(list(c1, c2), idcol = "dataID")
plotDat$dataID <- as.factor(plotDat$dataID)

# plot without group
ggplot(plotDat, aes(v1)) +
  geom_histogram()

# plot with group
ggplot(plotDat, aes(v1, fill = dataID, colour = dataID)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

А вот так на одном графике совместить гистограмму и регрессионную прямую

```
ggplot( baza ) +    
  geom_histogram(aes(x =  a)) + 
  geom_smooth( aes(x = a, y = b, group = c, color = c ))
```